# In XSD, how do you show mixed content?

Tags: xml, xsd

Given the following line in a DTD file:

`<!ELEMENT FIGURE (#PCDATA|PART)+>`

How would I go about making that into xsd format?

This is valid dtd and appears in the HTML dtd file: [from w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mixed="true"`:

```
<xs:element name="FIGURE">
  <xs:complexType mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="PART" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```